# Does the ruby File object constructor load the entire file into memory

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understanding what happens when I create a ruby File object.

The case have in mind is whether I can create a File object for a file while on one branch of the source tree and then switch branches and then still be able to access the file from the previous branch via the in initial file object I created.

So something like this:

```
repo = Rugged::Repository.new('path/to/repo/')
repo.checkout("test_branch")
file = File.new('path/to/repo/file.xml') 
repo.checkout("master")

file.read # hopefully reading a file from the `test_branch`
```

I'm hoping that `file.read` would now be reading the file from the `test_branch` even though I checked-out the repo back to master branch.

Will this work?

Comment: Don't keep us hanging :-) does it work?

Answer (score 0):

`File.new` is lazy and does not load the whole file into to memory. You must `read` it to get it contents. Do a simple test, create a file, open it with `File.new` and modify its content before reading.

Comment: so if I modified the above to `file = File.new('path/to/repo/file.xml').read` then this should work